# Convert a table with a pivot: Select rows to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have data that needs to be shifted as follows:

[image: Before & After]

I have been struggling with a stored procedure approach using a temp table to group the SKUs and then build the output but it is very slow. Now I just found out the PIVOT keyword. I would appreciate it if someone can show me how to convert using the PIVOT.

Please, note the struggle is with the FeeName column as it's values become the new three (for now) columns in the result.

**Create table:**

```
USE [Test];
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order]
(
    [Id] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NOT NULL,
    [OrderId] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [FeeName] [VARCHAR](25) NOT NULL,
    [Amount] [MONEY] NOT NULL,
    [SKU] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [VARCHAR](100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Order_Id]
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
        WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
              ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF
             ) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY];
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Order] ([Id], [OrderId], [FeeName], [Amount], [SKU], [Description]) VALUES (N'ce62e8a8-6650-4466-b629-086cc5b5db79', 12346, N'Item Fee', 100.0000, 789, N'Third')
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Order] ([Id], [OrderId], [FeeName], [Amount], [SKU], [Description]) VALUES (N'3229c09d-9562-4497-811e-0e0c2da022bc', 12347, N'Item Fee', 100.0000, 123, N'First')
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Order] ([Id], [OrderId], [FeeName], [Amount], [SKU], [Description]) VALUES (N'dc97d7c3-f31b-422e-be50-1197d67becdd', 12345, N'Commission', 125.0000, 789, N'Third')
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Order] ([Id], [OrderId], [FeeName], [Amount], [SKU], [Description]) VALUES (N'c8951c07-1070-4962-b4e4-1890d8cbc767', 12345, N'Penalty', 150.0000, 123, N'First')
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Order] ([Id], [OrderId], [FeeName], [Amount], [SKU], [Description]) VALUES (N'4faf4cf1-18ef-4fbe-bb13-19345575d981', 12346, N'Penalty', 150.0000, 123, N'First')
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Order] ([Id], [OrderId], [FeeName], [Amount], [SKU], [Description]) VALUES (N'03ae5fc7-8df2-4ea1-9186-1dc710d21d96', 12345, N'Penalty', 150.0000, 456, N'Second')
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Order] ([Id], [OrderId], [FeeName], [Amount], [SKU], [Description]) VALUES (N'a19a57ed-f56c-443b-8694-2c262bf40fb0', 12346, N'Penalty', 150.0000, 789, N'Third')
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Order] ([Id], [OrderId], [FeeName], [Amount], [SKU], [Description]) VALUES (N'5cac38cd-6e49-4d50-b644-2e42cff6faa3', 12346, N'Commission', 125.0000, 123, N'First')
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Order] ([Id], [OrderId], [FeeName], [Amount], [SKU], [Description]) VALUES (N'f5909f7c-54da-49aa-a0e9-4123a404a8ff', 12347, N'Penalty', 150.0000, 456, N'Second')
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Order] ([Id], [OrderId], [FeeName], [Amount], [SKU], [Description]) VALUES (N'1b821e19-781c-4ca3-ba7d-41e8a0ef10c2', 12346, N'Item Fee', 100.0000, 123, N'First')
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Order] ([Id], [OrderId], [FeeName], [Amount], [SKU], [Description]) VALUES (N'f005fdc1-04e5-4bdc-9b89-433589ed8e39', 12346, N'Penalty', 150.0000, 456, N'Second')
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Order] ([Id], [OrderId], [FeeName], [Amount], [SKU], [Description]) VALUES (N'77800636-35bd-4528-8171-4ae44c9edf14', 12345, N'Item Fee', 100.0000, 456, N'Second')
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Order] ([Id], [OrderId], [FeeName], [Amount], [SKU], [Description]) VALUES (N'120a6dd8-75a5-4c03-a319-511a137ea2f1', 12345, N'Penalty', 150.0000, 789, N'Third')
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Order] ([Id], [OrderId], [FeeName], [Amount], [SKU], [Description]) VALUES (N'589d0383-f2f7-475c-b84f-56dda1561a8f', 12345, N'Commission', 125.0000, 456, N'Second')
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Order] ([Id], [OrderId], [FeeName], [Amount], [SKU], [Description]) VALUES (N'3322b7a2-8173-470b-a92b-5b9edbddcd69', 12345, N'Item Fee', 100.0000, 790, N'Fourth')
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Order] ([Id], [OrderId], [FeeName], [Amount], [SKU], [Description]) VALUES (N'4aeb5d9e-0e8a-4111-a81d-65cccba9cd28', 12345, N'Commission', 125.0000, 790, N'Fourth')
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Order] ([Id], [OrderId], [FeeName], [Amount], [SKU], [Description]) VALUES (N'fbc02e3c-db5a-4e1a-bf28-6878ca244fc4', 12345, N'Item Fee', 100.0000, 789, N'Third')
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Order] ([Id], [OrderId], [FeeName], [Amount], [SKU], [Description]) VALUES (N'9050d591-5ddd-44a8-a752-69a3ee0e3a87', 12347, N'Commission', 125.0000, 123, N'First')
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Order] ([Id], [OrderId], [FeeName], [Amount], [SKU], [Description]) VALUES (N'239ebb6c-adb9-4946-a9a1-760f5cf6ec00', 12347, N'Commission', 125.0000, 456, N'Second')
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Order] ([Id], [OrderId], [FeeName], [Amount], [SKU], [Description]) VALUES (N'0ef5aa3f-f300-4498-b883-775187a2fc67', 12345, N'Penalty', 150.0000, 790, N'Fourth')
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Order] ([Id], [OrderId], [FeeName], [Amount], [SKU], [Description]) VALUES (N'9e4dcf8e-e49d-429e-8d05-a315567e9562', 12347, N'Penalty', 150.0000, 123, N'First')
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Order] ([Id], [OrderId], [FeeName], [Amount], [SKU], [Description]) VALUES (N'fa82700d-6dc8-4765-921a-ad38bb2e7f3b', 12346, N'Commission', 125.0000, 789, N'Third')
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Order] ([Id], [OrderId], [FeeName], [Amount], [SKU], [Description]) VALUES (N'84a9cfac-0c10-4c33-b04b-b66b3c4f53a2', 12346, N'Commission', 125.0000, 456, N'Second')
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Order] ([Id], [OrderId], [FeeName], [Amount], [SKU], [Description]) VALUES (N'b6e8ded6-43ee-4e67-8c53-b7da2a8f2141', 12347, N'Penalty', 150.0000, 789, N'Third')
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Order] ([Id], [OrderId], [FeeName], [Amount], [SKU], [Description]) VALUES (N'95867794-1fbb-455e-ab94-d37fcda499af', 12347, N'Item Fee', 100.0000, 789, N'Third')
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Order] ([Id], [OrderId], [FeeName], [Amount], [SKU], [Description]) VALUES (N'64f3ecc6-0a43-4204-b5b0-dd1dd21e1eb2', 12346, N'Item Fee', 100.0000, 456, N'Second')
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Order] ([Id], [OrderId], [FeeName], [Amount], [SKU], [Description]) VALUES (N'647f63c3-d2ba-4fc1-9169-e5525db9d4d9', 12345, N'Commission', 125.0000, 123, N'First')
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Order] ([Id], [OrderId], [FeeName], [Amount], [SKU], [Description]) VALUES (N'd4115a4e-a149-4a0b-89a6-f4cfdaf8f57f', 12347, N'Item Fee', 100.0000, 456, N'Second')
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Order] ([Id], [OrderId], [FeeName], [Amount], [SKU], [Description]) VALUES (N'd93a6e0f-f6ce-4d29-8894-fb0d858d4095', 12347, N'Commission', 125.0000, 789, N'Third')
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Order] ([Id], [OrderId], [FeeName], [Amount], [SKU], [Description]) VALUES (N'12e3df48-f63f-4e1e-b87e-fc4da7c30eac', 12345, N'Item Fee', 100.0000, 123, N'First')
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Order] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Order_Id]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [Id]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Order] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Order_Amount]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Amount]
GO
```

Comment: It would be helpful if instead of posting your sample data in an image if you provided it in text format. Even better would be a sample data set with insert statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a discrepancy in your screenshot ("Item Credit") vs your sample data ("Item Fee"), and it's a bit hard to see the result because you have re-used the same `Amount` over and over, but I think this is what you want:

```
select OrderId, [Item Fee], [Commission], [Penalty], SKU, Description
from 
(
    select OrderId, FeeName, Amount, SKU, Description from [Order]
) as src
pivot
(
    max(Amount)
    for FeeName in ([Item Fee], [Commission], [Penalty])
) piv;
```

Comment: Item Credit, Commission, & Penalty aren't o be the columns after transformation. They are values of FeeName

Comment: Then why does your screenshot titled "data that needs to be shifted as follows" show them as columns?

Comment: That is the weirdest typo on my part. `aren't o be` should be `are to be`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using conditional aggregation for this. This is a standard technique that works across most (if not all) RDBMS, unlike vendor-specific implementation of `pivot`. Also, it is usually as fast, or even faster, than specific implementations (that usually rely on conditional aggregation behind the hood).

```
select
    OrderID,
    max(case when FeeName = 'Item' Credit' then Amount end) [Item Credit],
    max(case when FeeName = 'Commission' then Amount end) [Commission],
    max(case when FeeName = 'Penalty' then Amount end) [Penalty],
    SKU,
    Description
from [Order]
group by 
    OrderID,
    SKU,
    Description
order by 
    OrderID,
    SKU,
    Description
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle with your sample data](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ebcd1f1194b024d0bebe53708b11edcb)**:

```
OrderID | Item Fee | Commission | Penalty  | SKU | Description
------: | :------- | :--------- | :------- | --: | :----------
  12345 | 100.0000 | 125.0000   | 150.0000 | 123 | First      
  12345 | 100.0000 | 125.0000   | 150.0000 | 456 | Second     
  12345 | 100.0000 | 125.0000   | 150.0000 | 789 | Third      
  12345 | 100.0000 | 125.0000   | 150.0000 | 790 | Fourth     
  12346 | 100.0000 | 125.0000   | 150.0000 | 123 | First      
  12346 | 100.0000 | 125.0000   | 150.0000 | 456 | Second     
  12346 | 100.0000 | 125.0000   | 150.0000 | 789 | Third      
  12347 | 100.0000 | 125.0000   | 150.0000 | 123 | First      
  12347 | 100.0000 | 125.0000   | 150.0000 | 456 | Second     
  12347 | 100.0000 | 125.0000   | 150.0000 | 789 | Third
```